# How to get RowID from google fusion table

Tags: android, google-fusion-tables, app-inventor

I have been using Google Fusion Tables with App Inventor, so there isn't much info out there other than that Pizza Party Tutorial. I've been looking at SQL solutions and such for the formatting of queries, but I just can't seem to get it right it appears. I am attempting to use the following code:[image]

in order to find the rowid of a row in my fusion table. However, whenever I send the query, I get the following error: Attempt to get item number 2 of a list of length 1: (51)
51 is the number I want, yet for some reason it is accessing the index 2 and I am not sure why.

[image]

This is the code that runs when I receive a result, but I never get a result because the query is apparently accessing index 2 or something. I tried to change the last line to say index 2, but I still got the same error - there's still an error for saying index 1...

Comment: display the result in a label and use *Do it* to debug your blocks, see also tip 4 here [Top 5 Tips: How to learn App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php) ... you still did not remove the blocks below the `SendQuery` method... everything after sending a query should continue in the `GotResult` event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FusiontableControl` component works asynchronously, which means, you send the query and in the `FusiontableControl.GotResult` event you receive the result. Therefore the blocks after your `SendQuery` method do not make much sense...

In the `FusiontableControl.GotResult` event your result will look like this

rowid
51

Inside that event use the `split` block to split the `result` at `\n` (new line) to get a list and select the 2nd item from the list using the `select list item` block  to get the value 51. You also can add some error handling and check, if the length of the list is > 1 before selecting the 2nd item...

Comment: Ok that makes a little more sense. And I have a method that handles the result, but the problem is that there is no result because it says the list is of length 1 - I don't understand where I'm attempting to access something at index 2. I'll add in the result method to my question...